# Is there a way to reduce the height of the accordion in codename?

Tags: codenameone

[image: Screenshot]

I incorporated an accordion in my sidemenu as seen in the image. The Home and Logout are not in the accordion, so their height differs. I request for help on how to reduce the height of the accordion header.

I also request for help on how I can remove the border of an accordion. I tried setting the border to empty in the accordion's UIID but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the padding and font of the elements in the accordion to reduce the height of the accordion. This also lets you control the border.

You can find the applicable UIIDs in the component inspector tool. Specifically UIIDs to look at would be `AccordionArrow` and `AccordionItem`.